# Scale Large MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is growing very quickly, Currently it has 47000000+ rows.

Even very simple queries such as this is taking **46** seconds at times.

```
SELECT id, userId, visitorId, date FROM  user_views LIMIT 20000000, 1;
```

Table structure is :

```
Field      Type             Null  Key   Default Extra
id         int(11)unsigned  NO    PRI   NULL    auto_increment
userId     int(11)unsigned  NO    MUL   NULL     
visitorId  int(11)          NO    MUL   NULL     
date       datetime         NO    MUL   NULL
```

Already the application is running with 1 master and 6 slaves. Cant afford more instances.

Have btree index on id

Is there any way to make it faster?

Thanks

Comment: At 46 seconds for such a simple query I don't think any performance fixes would be sufficient. But I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should consider using different storage approaches. Depending on your use cases a relational database might not be the best choice. E.g. if 99% of all oprations are writing to the table but not updating existing records (what your column names suggest), a nosql database might perform way better.

Secondly skipping 20000000 rows without any specific order criteria (based on an index of course) leaves it open to the DBMS to apply an arbitrary order, that might be suboptimal.

I don't know MySQL-internal optimization mechanisms, but LIMIT is only applied **after** the whole resultset has been built, which means you have the whole table loaded in your memory. So please try to reduce the size of the result set using WHERE statements **before** LIMITing it.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a good idea moving this data to a different storage system can help reduce load on database servers substantially. :-)